# no loop for break/next, jumping to top level error in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, sampling

I am trying to run this code and can't seem to avoid the error 'no loop for break/next, jumping to top level in R. This code worked previously but randomly began showing this error after seemingly no change. Not sure if it is a simple syntax error that I'm missing or something larger.

```
set.seed(440)
library(ggplot2)
alpha <- 1
xset <- seq(-5, 5 , .001) 
zdat <- data.frame(x=xset, y=dlaplace(xset, 1/alpha, 1))
rejection_sampling = function(n, alpha) {

f = dnorm(xset,0,1)

g = dlaplace(xset,0,1) 

  c <- sqrt(2*exp(1)/pi)
  
  x_sample <- numeric(n)
  current_n <- 1 
  total_samples <- 0
  
  while(current_n <= n) {
    
   
    y <- dlaplace(1,1,1)
    total_samples <- total_samples + 1
    

    a <- rbinom(1, 1, f / (g*c))
    

    if(a == 1) {
      x_sample[current_n] = y
      current_n <- current_n + 1
    }
  }
  

  list(
    x_sample,
    total_samples
  )
}


rejection_results = rejection_sampling(10000, 1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data=data.frame(x=rejection_results[[1]]),
                 mapping=aes(x=x, y=..density..),
                 bins=30, fill="white", color="black") +
  geom_line(data=zdat, color="blue", mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme_classic()
```

Comment: What is `dlaplace`? I can't run the code  then

Comment: it returns the density function of the laplace distribution. It requires the package (VGAM), which I have installed and loaded earlier in this code

Comment: This runs fine on my machine. Plot looks correct. Try restarting R and running it again.

Comment: For me it seemed to be hung at `rejection_results = rejection_sampling(10000, 1)` and when I executed a break operation I got the message that it was in the middle of `dlaplace(1, 1, 1)` and can see that `n` returns `[1] 100`. Maybe the example should be tailored so that it can complete in less than geologic time? I'm not a teenager but also not willing to sit in front of my screen for more than 30 minutes. Is `n` set in the code above? If I delete the data object named `n` it is now seen as a function name, from the tidyverse, no doubt.